# Warning: Illegal string offset from if statement

Tags: php

I am seeing the below error on my page:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'status' in XXX on line 344

**Line 344/335**

```
if ($status['status'] == '1') {
    echo"<font color='green'> Live </font>"; 
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong/why im seeing this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$status` is a string, not an array and you are using it as an array. You can access a string as an array in PHP but you have to provide valid numeric indexes for that. For example `$status[0]` will give you first character. `'status'` is no such valid index.

Comment: How should the line be wrote?

Comment: First you'll have to tell us what's the output of  `var_dump($status);` so we know how it looks like. Currently we don't